# Есть метод, который возвращает значение от числа a до числа b включительно. Как включить число a в этот отрезок?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

число b включил, а как включить a - не могу разобраться

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumberMethod {
    public int c;
    public int randomNumber (int a,int b){
        Random random = new Random();
        if (b>a) {
            c = random.nextInt(b - a) + a+1;
        }else{
            if (b<a) {
                c = random.nextInt(a - b) + b+1;
            }else{
                c=a;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `random.nextInt(int n)` возвращает число от 0 до n-1. Поэтому нужно передать в него n+1 (т.е. увеличить верхнюю границу на 1 ДО передачи в метод), чтобы получить число из диапазона от 0 до n(=`(n+1)-1`) включительно:

```
public int randomNumber (int a, int b){
    int c;
    Random random = new Random();
    if (b>a) {
        b = b + 1;
        c = random.nextInt(b - a) + a;
    }else{
        if (b<a) {
            a = a + 1;
            c = random.nextInt(a - b) + b;
        }else{
            c=a;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```